# Problem 18 chapter 4 from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Question: Every rational $x$ can be written in the form $x = m/n$, where $n > 0$, and $m$ and $n$ are integers without any common divisors. When $x=0$, we take $n=1$. Consider the function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^1$ by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &x\notin\mathbb Q, \\ \frac{1}{n} &x\in\mathbb Q. \end{cases}$$
Prove that $f$ is continuous at every irrational point, and that $f$ has a simple discontinuity at every rational point. 
My proof:
For any real number $x$, let $\epsilon>0$ be given, then there exists positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.
We have the unique integer $K$ such that $\frac{K}{N}\le x< \frac{K+1}{N}$. 
Let
$$\delta=\min\{\{x-\frac{K}{N},\frac{K+1}{N}-x \} \cap \mathbb{R^+} \} $$
For any $t$ such that $0<|t-x|<\delta$: if  $t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, $f(t)=0<\epsilon$；  if $t\in \mathbb{Q}$, $f(t)<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.
So it follows that $\lim_{t \to x } f(t)=0$.
If $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, since $f(x)=0=\lim_{t \to x } f(t)$, $f$ is continuous at every irrational point.
If $x \in\mathbb{Q}$, since $f(x)\neq0=\lim_{t \to x } f(t)$, $f$ has a simple discontinuity at every rational point.
Is my proof correct? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks good to me.